# Python Help, Max Number of Entries

Tags: python

Created a program for an assignment that requests we make a program that has the user input 20 numbers, and gives the highest, lowest etc. I have the main portion of the program working. I feel like an idiot asking this but I've tried everything setting the max number of entries and everything I've tried still lets the user submit more than 20. any help would be great! I tried max_numbers = 20 and then doing for _ in range(max_numbers) etc, but still no dice.

Code:

```
numbers = []

while True:
    user_input = input("Enter a number: ")
    if user_input == "":
        break
    try:
        number = float(user_input)
    except:
        print('You have inputted a bad number') 
    else:
        numbers.append(number)

for i in numbers:
    print(i, end=" ")


total = sum(numbers)
print ("\n")
print("The total amount is {0}".format(str(total)))
print("The lowest number is {0}".format(min(numbers)))
print("The highest number is {0}".format(max(numbers)))
mean = total / len(numbers)
print("The mean number is {0}".format(str(mean)))
```

Comment: You don't have "20" anywhere in your program. How would you expect it to guess you need 20 entries?..

Comment: show the code where you have put the max_numbers and please format indentation properly.

Comment: i mentioned in the description what i had tried so far and left out

Comment: @user3358965 Fix your indentation. As it stands, it will not run.

Answer (score 1):

Your question could be presented better, but from what you've said it looks like you need to modify the while condition.

```
while len(numbers) < 20:
    user_input = input("Enter a number:" )
    ....
```

Now once you've appending 20 items to the numbers list, the script will break out of the while loop and you can print the max, min, mean etc.

Answer (score 0):

Each time the user enters input, add `1` to a variable, as such:

```
numbers = []
entered = 0

while entered < 20:
    user_input = input("Enter a number: ")
    if user_input == "":
        break
    else:
        numbers.append(number)

    try:
        number = float(user_input)
    except:
        print('You have inputted a bad number')
        continue

for i in numbers:
print(i, end=" ")

total = sum(numbers)
print ("\n")
print("The total amount is {0}".format(str(total)))
print("The lowest number is {0}".format(min(numbers)))
print("The highest number is {0}".format(max(numbers)))
mean = total / len(numbers)
print("The mean number is {0}".format(str(mean)))
entered+=1
```

Every time the `while` loop completes, `1` is added to the variable `entered`. Once `entered` = `20`, the `while` loop breaks, and you can carry on with your program. Another way to do this is to check the length of the list `numbers`, since each time the loop completes you add a value to the list. You can call the length with the built-in function `len()`, which returns the length of a list or string:

```
>>> numbers = [1, 3, 5, 1, 23, 1, 532, 64, 84, 8]
>>> len(numbers)
10
```

**NOTE:** My observations were conducted from what I ascertained of your indenting, so there might be some misunderstandings. Next time, please try to indent appropriately.

Comment: I assume the point of the try/except block was to stop the user appending any data type except a number to the list - for example float('hello') raises a ValueError exception. So by appending to the list before this check, you've defeated the point. Also incrementing some arbitary number to track the length of another object is not a pythonic idiom - len(numbers) is the way to go.